# CSS - Can i change div .a background-color when .b:hover?

Tags: html, css, colors, background

I need to do the **reverse** of this:

JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rmdb94/nutar/)

HTML

```
<div class="a"> </div>
<div class="b"> </div>
```

CSS

```
.a{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;   
    background-color:blue;
}

.b{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:red;   
}

.a:hover + .b{
    background-color:green; 
}
```

I tried this:

```
.b:hover + .a{
    background-color:green; 
}
```

But it doesn't work. Is here any method to change my .a background-color when my .b is hover??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTMl

```
<div class="a"> </div>
<div class="b"> </div>
```

css

```
.a{
width:100px;
height:100px;   
background-color:blue;
}

.b{
width:100px;
height:100px;
background-color:red;   
}
 .hover{
background-color:green;
}
```

and add some Jquery,it will add your Need

```
$(".b").hover(function(){
$(".a").addClass("hover") 
});
```

by above you can have basic idea how to acomplish your task, get idea from here and accomplish your task

earlier
http://jsfiddle.net/Z7LaT/
now
http://jsfiddle.net/Z7LaT/2/

furthur,you can use MouseOver,MouseOut to toggle as per your Need

Comment: Okay, thats what i need, but i need to, when "stop hovering" .b the .a background-color come back to the original.. and i dont know how to do that, but thanks.

Comment: I have Updated the Link,Please Go back and Check ...@RodrigoBeloWebdesign

Comment: Enjoy Coding buddy :)